# FetchXML Localization

Tags: dynamics-crm, liquid, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-portals

I have a FetchXML Query that returns the correct entities for my portal.

How do I get the translated values stored in my CRM

```xml
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
    <entity name="testentity">
        <attribute name="xyz_testclassification" />
        <attribute name="xyz_schemaname" />
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Perhaps this article will help... [Enable multiple-language portal support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/enable-multiple-language-support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with XML and assuming attribute "xyz_testclassification" is an option set type your FetchXML query could return a resultset like this:

```xml
<resultset morerecords="0">
  <result>
    <xyz_testclassification name="Option One" formattedvalue="10003">10003</xyz_testclassification><xyz_schemaname>One</xyz_schemaname>
  </result>
  <result />
  <result>
    <xyz_testclassification name="Option Two" formattedvalue="10004">10004</xyz_testclassification><xyz_schemaname>Two</xyz_schemaname>
  </result>
  <result>
    <xyz_testclassification name="Option Three" formattedvalue="10001">10001</xyz_testclassification><xyz_schemaname>Three</xyz_schemaname>
  </result>
</resultset>
```

Here XML attribute "name" contains the display name of the option value. Attribute "formattedvalue" is only useful for numeric attributes (int, decimal, double, money).

When you are using FetchXML in C#, method `IOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple` will return `Entity` objects. The `Entity` class has a `FormattedValues` collection containing the display values.

All values are returned according to the language and formatting settings of the user on behalf of whom the system is queried.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Henk van Boeijen. I'd like to add that if you using the Web Api endpoint it is also possible by adding "Prefer: odata.include-annotations="OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue" in the header of the request.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
OData-Version: 4.0
Preference-Applied: odata.include-annotations="OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"

{
 "@odata.context": "[Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#accounts(name,donotpostalmail,accountratingcode,numberofemployees,revenue)",
 "value": [
 {
  "@odata.etag": "W/"502170"",
  "name": "Fourth Coffee (sample)",
  "donotpostalmail@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Allow",
  "donotpostalmail": false,
  "accountratingcode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Default Value",
  "accountratingcode": 1,
  "numberofemployees@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "9,500",
  "numberofemployees": 9500,
  "revenue@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "$100,000.00",
  "revenue": 100000,
  "accountid": "89390c24-9c72-e511-80d4-00155d2a68d1",
  "transactioncurrencyid_value": "50b6dd7b-f16d-e511-80d0-00155db07cb1" } ]
}
```

For more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx

Comment: Should I am to use ODATA over FetchXML?

Comment: FetchXML is useful in plugins and OData/WebApi is useful in javascript. Learn both